# Using background for only one function

Tags: java, processing

I was working on an animation on [processing](https://processing.org/). Then, I have a question about the code. Normally, my code is more long. However, I made a simple code which can usefull also for the beginners. My sample code:

```
int x1 = 0;
int x2 = 0;

void setup() {
  size(500, 100); // create a screen
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  drawRectangle();
  drawPoint();
}

void drawRectangle() {
  rect(x1, 20, 20, 20); // rect(x, y, width,height);
  x1 +=5;
}

void drawPoint() {
  point(x2, 20); // point(x, y);
  x2++;
}
```

So, I have points and rectangle in the same direction. The `background` effects both. However, the background shouldn't effect the points. As I want to make a line with points. The background should effect only the rectangle.
The solution should look like:
[image]

Comment: So you want to have a trail behind `shape1`?

Comment: Yes, shape1 should repeat itself. So,there are multiple rectangles intertwined on output. (It looks like there is no background for rectangle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to take a much simpler approach to this. Instead of drawing a line with multiple points, draw an actual line instead! And you can use only 1 `x` too.

This is a small example program, that produces the following output:

```
int x = 10, y = 50;

void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
  rectMode(CENTER); // So the values you give rect() are seen as the center of the rectangle
}

void draw() {
  background(255);

  drawLine();
  drawRectangle();

  x += 3;
}

void drawLine() {
  strokeWeight(5); // Make the line more visible
  line(0, y, x, y); // Draw a line from the left of the screen to x
  strokeWeight(1); // Return to standard
}

void drawRectangle() {
  fill(255, 0, 0); // Make the color red
  rect(x, y, 20, 20); // Draw the rectangle
}
```

[image: An example]

Comment: Hımm, thanks. Actually your answer is kind of true for this question. However, it doesn't reach to my goal. Probably I asked wrongly. I will upvote your answer. However, is there any way to make that in draw function?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Maybe you could provide a drawing of what you are trying to achieve?